# Not able to create instance for viewcontroller in other viewcontrollers in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I have a viewcontroller with  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) , i want to create instance in other class. here is my code

> ```
> class ViewControllerB: UIViewController { 
> @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
>
> required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
>     super.init(coder: aDecoder)
> }}
> ```

I want to create instance for ViewControllerB in ViewControllerA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it in a few ways.

**Option 1**

```
let viewController = ViewControllerB(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```

**Option 2**

Change your ViewControllerB like following.

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    convenience init () {
        self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

OR

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }
    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }
    convenience override init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
    }
}
```

And now you can call

```
let viewController = ViewControllerB()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
let viewController = ViewControllerB()
```

This will give the instance of ViewControllerB and then do what you want.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, actually it has required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}}, so your answer doesnt work